# Creating internetShortcut in oneDrive with MicrosoftGraph

Tags: java, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to create a internetshortcut in a onedrive folder using microsoft graph, and my code does not seem to be working.

I can create the item, but i am not able to add the content to the item

```
    private static void createShortCut(String fileUrl,String fileName, String destinationPath){
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authTokenProvider).buildClient();

    DriveRequestBuilder driverReq = graphClient.sites(SharePointCopierConfig.SITE_ID).drive();
    DriveItemRequestBuilder driverRootReq = driverReq.root();

    DriveItemRequestBuilder destination = driverRootReq.itemWithPath(destinationPath);

    ItemReference destinationReference = new ItemReference();
    destinationReference.driveId = driverReq.buildRequest().get().id;
    destinationReference.id = destination.buildRequest().get().id;

    String contents = "[InternetShortcut]\nURL=" + fileUrl;
    byte[] bytes = contents.getBytes();

    //ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

    DriveItem newItem = new DriveItem();
    newItem.name = fileName+".url";
    newItem.file = new File();
    newItem.file.mimeType = "text/plain";

    graphClient.drives(destinationReference.driveId)
            .items(destinationReference.id)
            .children()
            .buildRequest()
            .post(newItem);

    graphClient.me().drive().items(newItem.id).content().buildRequest().put(bytes);

}
```

If anyone can help me find out where i am failing or has a better way i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create it, here is the method

```
public String createShortCut(String fileUrl,String fileName, String destinationPath) {
    try {
        long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authTokenProvider).buildClient();

        DriveRequestBuilder driverReq = graphClient.sites(SharePointCopierConfig.SITE_ID).drive();
        DriveItemRequestBuilder driverRootReq = driverReq.root();

        DriveItemRequestBuilder destination = driverRootReq.itemWithPath(destinationPath);

        ItemReference destinationReference = new ItemReference();
        destinationReference.driveId = driverReq.buildRequest().get().id;
        destinationReference.id = destination.buildRequest().get().id;

        DriveItem newItem = new DriveItem();
        newItem.name = fileName.replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "") + ".url";
        newItem.file = new com.microsoft.graph.models.File();
        newItem.file.mimeType = "text/plain";

        String urlContent = "[InternetShortcut]\nURL=" + fileUrl;
        byte[] stream = urlContent.getBytes();

        DriveItem createdDriveItem = destination.children().buildRequest().post(newItem);

        driverReq.items(createdDriveItem.id)
                .content()
                .buildRequest()
                .put(stream);

        long timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long timeSeconds = (timeEnd-timeStart);
        return fileName + " Shortcut Created Successful in "+timeSeconds+" ms";

    }catch (GraphServiceException exception) {
        logger.error(exception.getServiceError().code + " " + exception.getMessage());
        return "Error Creating url " + exception.getMessage();
    }
}
```